# angularJS $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am using onsen-ui, and my code is as below

```js
app.controller('AccountsController', function($scope, $http, AccountsData) {
        var accounts = {};

        //outputAccounts();

        $scope.Accounts = [];

        $http({method: 'GET', url: AccountsData.url}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.Accounts = data.result;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });

        $scope.viewAccount = function(index) {
            var selectedItem = $scope.Accounts[index];
            AccountsData.selectedItem = selectedItem;
            alert(selectedItem.name);
            $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('account.html', selectedItem);
        }

        $scope.showAcctModal = function($index) {

        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ons-page ng-controller="AccountsController">

    <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Accounts</div>
    <!--<div class="right">
        <ons-button modifier="quiet" ng-click="showAddModal()">Add</ons-button>    
    </div>-->
    </ons-toolbar>

    <ons-scroller>
         <ons-list id="accountlist" style="width: 100%">
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-repeat="account in Accounts" ng-click="viewAccount($index)">
                <ons-row>
                    <ons-col>
                    {{account.name}}
                    </ons-col>
                </ons-row> 
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
    </ons-scroller>  
</ons-page>
```

The issue when click on an list item (account name), there is alert pop up to show the account name, but it doesn't navigator to the page account.html. it seems the $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage is not working, pls help.

Comment: Where do you define you `<ons-navigator>` and where do you set `$scope.ons.navigator`? Do you have another controller that is a parent to this one?

Also, please tell what JavaScript error you get. If `$scope.ons.navigator` isn't defined you'll probably get an error saying that.

Comment: Ok, I defined my <ons-navigator> in my start page home.html, and i thought it will only need it once, i was wrong, after i added the <ons-navigator> to the current html file, ths navigator is working now, thanks for your point out.

Comment: I didn't see any javascript error, i am using monaca debugger

Comment: @Andreas Argelius, I still having issue, from my home.html, i navigator to another page by ons.navigator.pushPage("xxx.html"), anyway, in the xxx.html, I want to go back to home.html not via the back button, i tried to use $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage("home.html"), but not working; I tried to add <ons-navigator> around the xxx.html, also not work,  and tried window.history.back(), no luck, can you help?

Comment: Use `navigator.popPage()` to go back. The navigator maintains a page stack. Please read the Onsen UI documentation: http://onsen.io/ .

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry i didn't read the doc thoroughly :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sliding menu then try the following to switch page:

$scope.ons.slidingMenu.setMainPage("home.html", {closeMenu: true});